# Informal history of Crazy Rummy and/or Frustration?

Tags: house-rules, rummy

It's my understanding that Gin Rummy was 'codified' in 1909 and that Rummy games in general are thought to be 'descended' from Conquian.

And I realize that minor variants tend to be more of a 'house rule' flavor and don't have 'official rules' write-ups.

So this is essentially an informal poll, but I'm wondering about two games that I've played with family over the years (but never thought until now to trace how they were introduced).

These both fit in the Contract category; the main differences are:

- in our [Crazy Rummy](https://www.adda52.com/blog/how-to-play-crazy-rummy), assigned melds always consist of sets of 3 and/or runs of 4; you can only build onto your own melds; the number of cards dealt increases in later rounds to accommodate larger assignments; and each round everybody proceeds to the next assigned meld, regardless of whether or not they put down the previous one.
- in our [Frustration](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2008/nov/22/rules-card-games-frustration), the sizes of sets and runs range from 2-5 and 3-9 respectively; each player is 'stuck' with an assignment from round to round if they don't manage to put it down before someone else goes out; and once your assignment's been put down you can build on any others that have also been put down.

I don't expect to discover "X was invented by Q in 19__" - I'm just wondering how long ago anyone can recall playing or hearing about either of these.  I first played the Crazy variant in the early 1980s, and Frustration in 2010.  The group who introduced me to the latter had never heard of the former (and didn't like it when they tried it); the group who introduced me to the former have passed on.

(And if anyone has known the same concepts by other names, I hope it isn't a serious breach of the one-question-one-answer principle for that to be a follow-up/side issue.)